# I have changed file location, but it seems to not accept

Tags: c#

I get this error when tring to change file location;

An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\Asus VivoBook X442U\source\repos\GameShop\GameShop\games.txt'.

The file path I am trying to use is;
C:\Users\Ryanb\Music\GameShop\GameShop\games.txt

Here is my code

```
public void readFromFile()
    {
        string[] games = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\Ryanb\Music\GameShop\GameShop\games.txt");
        foreach(string gameString in games)
        {
            string[] gameArray = gameString.Split(',');
```

Comment: There is dot at the end of the path. What is it?

Comment: Youi've specified a folder name. I don't see a filename. In addition, the `.` at the end before the final `);` is not valid and should cause a compiler error, as it's outside the quotes. What is it supposed to mean? You also don't need to post an image of your entire desktop for a text error message. Copy and paste (or type) the error message directly into your quesiton. At the very least, you could crop the image to a reasonable size.

Comment: I removed the dot, it was a mistake.

Comment: it's all good now?

Comment: Sorry, edited the code and still get "An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.dll"

Comment: `GameShop` is a file right? If so you need to to check `if (File.Exist(@"C:\Users\Ryanb\OneDrive\Desktop\GameShop\GameShop"))` before calling the `ReadAllLines`

Comment: What is `games.txt` in above code? Why is not there in the new code?

Comment: Please throw away your huge image and copy the exception text into your question. If you format it as code, it is quite readable

Comment: Edited the question and removed the image. Hopefully it is more clear to read, sorry. "games.txt" is the file I want it to read from

Comment: Your text in your question, the code in your massive image and the exception message all specify different locations. Your "music" folder is probably redirected as part of your profile. If this is the current user, don't hard-core the folder. Use `Environment.SpecialFolders` instead

Comment: @Flydog57 For some odd reason, this issue got me intrigued. I am trying to reproduce this issue, but I always get a the Exception pointing to the same folder and not to a different one. I tried creating symbolic hard/soft links, to the file, to the folder and remove the folder/file. However **I could not reproduce the issue. In that sense it is a very ingesting case, that I would like to understand**. May be this is a window server, where redirection is possible.

Comment: @Juv: If a Windows system is running within an "Enterprise", the administrators can set up "Group Policy" that provides for "Folder Redirection".  This way, things like "My Documents" (or whatever Microsoft is calling it these days) can be located in a network location.  By doing that, the user can log into a different machine and have instance access to his/her documents.  Take a look at: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/storage/folder-redirection/folder-redirection-rup-overview, or just look up "Windows Folder Redirection"

Answer (score 0):

You can read Microsoft documentations about the [File.ReadAllLines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readalllines?view=netcore-3.1) method.

You can see there:

> DirectoryNotFoundException - The specified path is invalid (for example, it is on an unmapped drive).

The path is not right, try to follow it in file explorer.

In any case it is always good to check if the file exist:

```
public void readFromFile()
{
    if (File.Exist(@"C:\Users\Ryanb\OneDrive\Desktop\GameShop\GameShop\games.txt"))
    {
        string[] games = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\Ryanb\OneDrive\Desktop\GameShop\GameShop\games.txt".);
        foreach(string gameString in games)
        {
            string[] gameArray = gameString.Split(',');
            if (gameArray.Length == 7)
```

Comment: Follow the `C:\Users\Asus VivoBook X442U\source\repos\GameShop\GameShop\`

Comment: C:\Users\Asus VivoBook X442U\source\repos\GameShop\GameShop   Doesn't exist anymore.

Comment: You might have a broken link, follow C:\Users\Ryanb\OneDrive\Desktop\GameShop\GameShop\ and see where it is broken.

Comment: It takes me to exactly where the file is.

Comment: I suggest that you elaborate more on what you are trying to do. How do you get the `games.txt`, is it a file you created a third party program creates. May be other usful information. To let us understand your problem.

Comment: When you follow the path, does it remain the same in address line? Can you copy the file to. let say `C:\Temp` and see that it works?

Comment: Is the application you are debugging running for a while now? It might be that the system had some changes the application is not aware of (this is a long shot)

Comment: turns out all I had to do was change a "/" form "C:\Users\Ryanb\OneDrive\Desktop\GameShop\GameShop\games.txt" to "C:\Users\Ryanb\OneDrive\Desktop\GameShop\GameShop/games.txt" Thankyou for your answer and time

Comment: Interesting... no problem.